# Lines and drawables draw order in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

sorry for my english ;-P!

I'm writing an app that shows in google maps pipes and valves(lines and points). For that i've two classes.

One extends from ItemizedOverlay, and i add to map overlay one for each category of valve, and each one can have more than one item.

The second extends from Overlay, and in the draw method y draw the line with the method drawline of the canvas.

The problem i've is that the lines are drawn over the ItemizedOverlay items, no matter the order i add them to the mapView.getOverlays().

I want the lines on the bottom of all overlays. is there a way to do that.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it! I didn't know that when you populate the itemizedovelay items, they automatically are added to the map, so i was populating them before adding the lineoverlays and after that i were adding them again.

The order you add them to getOverlays() affects correctly!!

Thks

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the zIndex value for thew overlays. The ones with the higher values will show up above the others :)